# How can I render a tmx map at a given location?

Tags: java, libgdx, tiled

I am using libgdx & trying to implement a *Binding of Issac* like dungeon. To do this I'm loading a [tmx map](http://doc.mapeditor.org/reference/tmx-map-format/) when a dungeon room is created and rendering it to the screen. The issue is that the each room renders the map in the same place on top of each other. This all boils down to one question: How can I render a map at a specific x,y position, so that I can display the whole dungeon at once?

Comment: It'd be easier to troubleshoot the issue if you posted an example of what you're doing or what you've tried thus far to solve the issue.

Comment: As far as I remember, Binding of Isaac always shows only one room at a time: the room the player is currently in. Do you want to do the same or do you want fluent scrolling between rooms?

Comment: I was going for a scrolling effect between the rooms

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: ***you can't***. A tiled map is always rendered at (0, 0). The only way to change this would be to implement some sort of hack; perhaps using VBOs to save each room to a texture then render it with an offset.

Comment: This answer seems speculative, and contradictory. If you can't, why are you suggesting that you can?

Comment: It's not contradictory at all. You can't render a *Tiled Map* at any other position than `(0, 0)` however you *can* render a VBO at any other position than `(0, 0)`.

Comment: How would you suggest I edit this answer to make it better?